# 503 Service Unavailable error Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, http-status-code-503

I try to deploy my Java project Apache Tomcat server but sometimes it gets down and returns me this page

[image: service unavailable 503]

Tomcat is installed on the [Digitalocean's](http://digitalocean.com) Ubuntu 14.04 and droplet's properties are 512Mb/1CPU, 20GB SSD Disk, 1000 GB transfer. I took the lowest option for test purposes. The site is visited by nobody except me and from the graphs I observe that the server is not overloaded at all. Most of the time everything works fine until suddenly the server returns 503. After I restart it keeps working fine again till the next 503 error in several days. I'd like to know what could cause this error: my mistake on configuring the server or maybe problems on server side?

Comment: You arn't giving any information that can be used to debug this. Have you looked around at the apache and the tomcat logs ?

Answer (score 0):

That mean tomcat is not running. You can use the alias command to up the tomcat service or just go in the current directory and start the service.

Example: # tomcatup
/opt/tomcat8/bin/startup.sh